# Aligning the tops of two tabularx environments

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I have used the following to place two tabularx environments next to each other

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{190pt}{l}
\toprule
... Content ...
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\quad
\begin{tabularx}{190pt}{l}
\toprule
... Content ...
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

How would I further align the tops of the two tabularx environments?

Comment: use the `[t]` argument on each of the `tabularx`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `[t]` argument on each of the `tabularx`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[l]{200pt}{%
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{190pt}{X}
\toprule
... Content ...\\\midrule
... Content ...\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[r]{200pt}{%
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{190pt}{X}
\toprule
... Content ...\\\midrule
... Content ...\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}}
\end{minipage}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]